# Investigate the convergence or divergence of the sequence:

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_0, ..., x_{p-1}$ be arbitrary numbers. For every $n \ge p$ $$x_n = a_1x_{n-1}+a_2x_{n-2}+ \ ... \ + a_px_{n-p}$$
where each $a_i$ is a given constant (not necessarily all equal).
The difficulty lies in the fact that there are no assumptions on the numbers $x_0, ..., x_{p-1}$ (except their value, but I mean that it can be positive or negative, we don't know) nor $a_1, ..., a_p$. We can deduce that if the sequence is to be convergent to a limit different from $0$:$$\sum a_i = 1$$. Is the previous equality also sufficient for convergence?
The sequence can be not monotonic: consider for instance the case when $p = 2, a_1 = a_2 = 1/2$. I should let you know that this exercise does not assume prior knowledge on series. I also tried to apply Cauchy general criterion for convergence, but without success. What do you suggest?

Comment: Try $a_1=2, a_2=-1$ with $x_0=1,x_1=0$.

Comment: I tried also the previous numbers you suggested, $x_0 = 1, x_1 = 0$ and found $x_n = 1-n$ so the sequence diverges.

Comment: But I was trying to find general conditions on convergence or divergence of the sequence. Of course if I take $a_1 = 1, x_0 = 1$ the sequence is convergent. Maybe there can be also indeterminate sequences.

Comment: Also I still left the $0$ limit possibility open

Comment: There are other counterexamples, like $a_1=3, a_2=-2$.  Your condition comes down to saying that $1$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial $x^p=a_1x^{p-1}+\cdots +a_p$ but you need to add constraints to force the other roots to be small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that taking $x_n=1\,\forall n$ gives a solution, supposing that $\sum a_n=1$.  Therefore I take the question to mean "given that $
\sum a_n=1$ must there be a non-constant solution to the recursion which converges to a non-zero value?"  And the answer to that is no:

A counterexample is given by $$x_n=2x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}$$
'
Starting with, say, $x_0=1, x_1=0$.

You may convince yourself that the general solution is  given by $x_n=An+B$ for some constants $A,B$ which depend on the initial conditions.  It follows that any solution is either constant or divergent.

The usual method for solving such recursions is to consider the $\textit {characteristic polynomial}$ for the recursion, $$x^p =a_1x^{p-1}+\cdots a_p$$  Then, if the roots are distinct, $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_p$ the general solution is of the form $$x_n=A_1\lambda_1^n+\cdots A_p\lambda_p^n$$

In order for the sequence to converge to something other than $0$ you need $1$ to be a root, which is where you get $\sum a_i=1$, and you need all the other roots to have norm $<1$.

Things get more complicated if the roots are not distinct.  The counterexample I gave has the polynomial $(x-1)^2$ for example.  But it's easy to produce more counterexamples.  Just write down any polynomial with $(x-1)$ as a factor and some big roots.

Comment: So in general I should say that a sufficient condition for convergence is that each root must be $<1$ in modulus.

Comment: Could some $A_i$ be $0$? As far as I know they are functions of the initial conditions, right?

Comment: Yes, the initial conditions matter.  I will edit to reflect that.